# ADXL345 reading only ceros

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, texas-instruments

Im trying to pair the [ADXL 345](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjR0Nuc7L3lAhVjOX0KHUrZDroQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparkfun.com%2Fdatasheets%2FSensors%2FAccelerometer%2FADXL345.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1mJW7y6Lgne_fe_DINtSWI) with the [tm4c1294nctpd](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1294ncpdt.pdf) using energia, 
The configuration of pins are the next
The SDA with the pin PB3 and the SCL with the PB2 (I2C0 port),  using the J1(3.3V) and J21(5V) and the GND.
Under the serial monitor of energia, the outputs are x=0,y=0, z=0,
, the circuit have the pull'up resistor in SDA and SCL pines,

The adress of the sensor is  0x53. I understand Im making the device the slave of the I2C protocol ( Wire.begin(ADXAddress);)

The code is

```
 #include "Wire.h"

#define Power_Register 0x2D
#define BW_rate 0x2C
#define Int_enable 0x2E
#define dataFormat 0x31
#define X_Axis_Register_DATAX0 0x32
#define X_Axis_Register_DATAX1 0x33
#define Y_Axis_Register_DATAY0 0x34 
#define Y_Axis_Register_DATAY1 0x35
#define Z_Axis_Register_DATAZ0 0x36
#define Z_Axis_Register_DATAZ1 0x37
#define fifoCntrl 0x38

int ADXAddress = 0x53;
int X0,X1,X_out;
int Y0,Y1,Y_out;
int Z1,Z0,Z_out;
float Xa,Ya,Za;

void setup() {
  Wire.setModule(0);
  Wire.begin(ADXAddress);   
  Serial.begin(9600);    
  delay(100);
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress);
  Wire.write(Power_Register);
  Wire.write(8);
  Wire.write(BW_rate);
  Wire.write(10);
  Wire.write(dataFormat);
  Wire.write(11);
  Wire.write(fifoCntrl);
  Wire.write(0);

  Wire.endTransmission();


}


void loop() {

 Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress);
 Wire.write(X_Axis_Register_DATAX0);
 Wire.write(X_Axis_Register_DATAX1);  
 Wire.endTransmission();
 Wire.requestFrom(ADXAddress,2);
 if(Wire.available()<=2) {   
   X0 = Wire.read();
   X1 = Wire.read();
   X1=X1<<8;
   X_out =X0+X1;

 }

 Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress); 
 Wire.write(Y_Axis_Register_DATAY0);
 Wire.write(Y_Axis_Register_DATAY1);  
 Wire.endTransmission(); 
 Wire.requestFrom(ADXAddress,2);
 if(Wire.available()<=2) { 
   Y0 = Wire.read();
   Y1 = Wire.read();
   Y1=Y1<<8;
   Y_out =Y0+Y1;
 }

 Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress); 
 Wire.write(Z_Axis_Register_DATAZ0);
 Wire.write(Z_Axis_Register_DATAZ1);  
 Wire.endTransmission(); 
 Wire.requestFrom(ADXAddress,2);
 if(Wire.available()<=2) { 
   Z0 = Wire.read();
   Z1 = Wire.read();
   Z1=Z1<<8;
   Z_out =Z0+Z1;

 }

 Serial.print("Xa= ");
 Serial.print(Xa);Serial.print("\t");
 Serial.print("Ya= ");
 Serial.print(Ya);Serial.print("\t");
 Serial.print("Za= ");
 Serial.println(Za);


 delay(1000);
 Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of board for the ADXL345? What do you mean by *... using the J1(3.3V) and J21(5V)...*? Your problem is likely hardware related, it would help if you explained a bit better how you are wiring your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing to random I2C registers you'll need to restart transmission. Just make a function to make this simpler.

```
void writeReg ( int reg, int value )
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress);
    Wire.write(reg);
    Wire.write(value);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setup() 
{
  Wire.setModule(0);
  Wire.begin(ADXAddress);   
  Serial.begin(9600);    
  delay(100);

  writeReg(Power_Register,8);
  writeReg(BW_rate,10); // <-- should this be 0x10 ?
  writeReg(dataFormat,11); // <-- should this be 0x11 ?
  writeReg(fifoCntrl,0);  // <-- this isn't strictly needed as fifoCntrl will be 0 at power on reset anyway

}
```

Secondly, the tutorial you have used (I have seen it on the web) is actually not 100% correct. When reading a register, it must write only one byte - not two before the read, once to set the register pointer. Simplify your code to make another function for reading to make it the code easier to read.

```
int readAxis ( int reg )
{
   Wire.beginTransmission(ADXAddress);
   Wire.write(reg);
   Wire.endTransmission();
   Wire.requestFrom(ADXAddress,2);

   int d0 = Wire.read();
   int d1 = Wire.read();

   return (d1<<8) + d0;
}

void loop ()
{
    X_out = readAxis(X_Axis_Register_DATAX0); // this will read TWO bytes starting from X0 register (LSB + MSB)
    Y_out = readAxis(X_Axis_Register_DATAY0);
    Z_out = readAxis(X_Axis_Register_DATAZ0);
    :
```

Thirdly you aren't actually printing anything because you forgot to set Xa, Ya, Za values

```
:

Xa = (float)X_out/RANGE;
Ya = (float)Y_out/RANGE;
Za = (float)Z_out/RANGE;


Serial.print("Xa= ");
Serial.print(Xa);Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print("Ya= ");
Serial.print(Ya);Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print("Za= ");
Serial.println(Za);
```

You'll need to define `RANGE` based on the full scale of your chosen ADXL output (in terms of G). Please check ADXL datasheet on your mode of operation (i.e. is it 2 G or 16 G operation etc... what are the fullscale values for each?)

```
#define ADXL_FULLSCALE 4096   // 2^(13 bits- 1 signed bit)
#define ADXL_FULLSCALE_G 16   // +/- 16 G operation
#define RANGE (ADXL_FULLSCALE /ADXL_FULLSCALE_G )
```